# numpy draw a few bernoulli distributions at once

Tags: python, numpy, random

Say I want to draw from a list of bernoulli distributions at once, e.g. with probabilities `[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]`. I could do this with a for loop but is there a better numpy way (use of scipy is also fine)?

```
ps = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
[np.random.choice(2, p=[1 - p, p]) for p in ps]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can draw `n=1` from a binomial, which is equivalent to Bernoulli. Since binomial accepts an array as the probability parameter, you can use:

```
np.random.binomial(1, p=ps)
```

You can test if it's working by giving very small/large probabilities to some elements and call the function several times.

For example, let `ps = [0.23, 0.48, 0.64, 0.98]`

```
In [90]: np.sum([np.random.binomial(1,p=ps) for i in range(100000)], axis=0)
Out[90]: array([23000, 48115, 64128, 97957])
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to rather use `(np.random.uniform(size=d) < probs) * 1`, where `probs` is your vector of probabilities. This generates uniform random variables that are then thresholded to be `0` or `1` and the probability of getting `1` is exactly what you have in `probs`.

If you need only a few bernoulli variables and just once the solution with np.random.binomial should be fine. However, it seems to be several times slower than generating bernoulli variables using uniform distribution. For instance, if we have some random vector of probabilities
`probs = np.uniform(size=10000)`, 
then we get

```
%timeit np.random.binomial(n=1, p=probs, size=10000)
Result: 775 µs ± 5.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit (np.random.uniform(size=10000) < probs) * 1
Result: 103 µs ± 510 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```